# about option buttons in User form

Tags: excel, user-controls, vba

I have a question:

I need to create a user form that contain that usual OK and Cancel Buttons. It also should contain two sets of Options buttons, each set placed inside a frame. The captions on the first set should be **basketball, baseball, football**, the captions on the second set should be **watch on TV** and **Go to games**.  I need to write the event handlers and code in a module so that when the program runs, the user sees the form.  If the user makes a couple of choices and clicks OK, he should see a message like "Your favorite sport is basketball, and you usually watch on TV." If the user clicks Cancel, the message "Sorry you don't want to play" should appear.

[image]

I think I almost have it working, but I don't know why I cannot successfully execute the Macro.

My Code is :

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()


MsgBox ("sorry if you don't want to play")
End Sub

Private Sub commandbuttons_Click()
Dim optbasket As String, optbaseball As String, optfootball As String
Dim optwog As String, optgtg As String

 Select Case True
 Case optbasket
   optbasket = True
 Case optbaseball
   optbaseball = True
 Case optfootball
   optfootball = True
  End Select

If optwog Then
  optwog = True
  Else
  optgtg = True
  End If

btnok = MsgBox("you favorite sport is " & Frame1.Value & "you usually " & Frame2.Value & ",")
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub btmcancel_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub btnok_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Frame1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Frame2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub optbaseball_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub optbasketball_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub optfootball_Click()

End Sub
```

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you're using.

Comment: Have you put the code under the correct event handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things here:

1. You should name your buttons to be "OkButton" and "CancelButton" or something like that. They'll be easier to track later. Same thing for your radio buttons (baseball, basketball, etc.)
2. You don't need your select statement or your if statement
3. I don't think Frame1 and Frame2 have a .Value property you can call
4. Here is some sample code. You would add an object to your worksheet that could be clicked on. In this example I just inserted a rectangle object. form the Insert tab. Then in the UserForm code, I renamed the Ok Button to be OkButton and added the function OkButton_click. When it is clicked, I capture the values of the radio buttons. I named them baseball, basketball, and football accordingly as well as watch and go. If one of them is true, then I assign "game" which is a string I declared to be the appropriate title of the game. I did the same thing for whether the person likes to go to the game or watch it. Then I added the CancelButton_Click function to close the userForm.

   ```
   Private Sub Rectangle1_Click()
      UserForm1.Show
   End Sub

   Private Sub OkButton_Click()
       Dim game as String, watchOrGo as String
       If baseball Then game = "baseball"
       If basketball Then game = "basketball"
       If football Then game = "football"

       If watch Then watchOrGo = "watch"
       If go then watchOrGo = "go"

       okbtn = Msg("Your favorite sport is " & game & ". You usually " & watchOrGo)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
       cnclbtn = Msg("Sorry you don't want to play")
       Unload Me
    End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code in `commandbuttons_Click()` to run when you click OK, you need to put it in the click handler for the OK button:  `btnok_Click()`; likewise for `CommandButton2_CLick()` and `btncancel_Click()`.

Comment: @Mars instead of thanks comments, you should vote up the answers that helped you; and, once your problem is solved, accept the one that (did the most to) solve your problem.

Comment: @Mars next to questions and answers are up/down arrows that let you vote.  Initially you're only allowed to vote on answers to you own questions; unrestricted up voting unlocks at 15 rep, down voting at 125.